# Missing autoconversion from bool into integer in Java

Tags: java, c

What is the equivalent of C `y -= m < 3;` in Java? That is part of [Sakamoto's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week#Sakamoto.27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (m < 3) {
   y--;
}
```

Comment: With one exception, which is that if you're writing the Java code based on a specification or sample implementation in a paper, which uses `y -= m < 3`, then you might value obviousness of the equivalence to the spec over readability of the Java code. If you're copying an algorithm you more or less don't care what the code does as long as it matches the definition, you can worry about that if and when you ever start innovating. Which in this case won't happen until 9999 unless we change the calendar first.

Comment: I suspected that but was not sure.

Comment: @Brian: Just read today: "Programmers who use every trick in the book to save a few microseconds of computing time at the expense of clarity are not in tune with the cost structure of today's world. You must write programs with people as well as computers in mind." (by J.J.Prichard and F.M.Carrano).

Answer (score 6):

You can write

```
y -= m < 3 ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I think an `if` is more clear here than a `ternary` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
y -= ( m < 3 ? 1 : 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (thereis no conversion boolean to int in java)

```
y -= (m<3)?1:0;
```

Answer (score 1):

That statement subtracts 1 from y if m is less than 3, that is, if the month is January or February.   There are several ways to code it in java, for example:

```
if (m<3) y = y-1;
if (m<3) --y;
y = (m<3)? y-1 : y;
y -= (m<3)? 1 : 0;
```

of which the first or second is perhaps clearest.

Comment: The third option ruins my day:)

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to keep it a bit obfuscated you can do `y -= m < 3 ? 1 : 0;`